# Spring boot builder error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, circuit-breaker

When I m going to add **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix** dependency into pom.xml file, the build was failed.
The project was already build with spring-cloud-gateway, netflix-eureka-client and bootstrap. I want to add spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix dependency into this project to enable circuit-breaker

[`ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 15`

Here I have mentioned **pom.xml** file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.yasas</groupId>
    <artifactId>order-service-api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order-service-api-gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors says you are missing version for `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix`. You can declare appropriate version under `<properties>` section something like (I am using latest version for example, you can use any appropriate version here)  :

```
<properties>
..
  <spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix.version>2.2.10.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix.version>
</properties>
```

& inside dependency tag:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried both ways you have mentioned. Same error is remaining

Comment: @YasasRanawaka, can you clean/delete your .m2 & run it again please?

Comment: Your first suggestion won't work because that property isn't going to be used anywhere. You could either use the property in the <version> tag, or go with your alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I used resilience4j circuitbreaker instead of hystrix. I worked as I expected in API-gateway service.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```